# Possible to integrate $\ln |x-y| dy$ on a circle?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am wondering what is the solution to
$$\int_{\partial D}\ln |x-y| dy$$

when $D$ is the unit disc in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $x \in \partial D$. Is this even possible analytically?

Comment: This seems unlikely since the integrand has a singularity on the proposed path of integration, right?

Comment: @MPW why would it seem so? The function $\ln |x|$ is integrable on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Yes it has a singularity but I assume that does not prevent integration for the reason @TZakrevskiy mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=x e^{i\theta}$, then the integral becomes

$$ \int_{[0,2\pi]}\ln|x(1-e^{i\theta})| d\theta =2\pi |x|+ \int_{[0,2\pi]}\ln|  1-e^{i\theta} | d\theta =2\pi+ \int_{[0,2\pi]}\ln|2-2\cos\theta| d\theta$$
$$= 2\pi+ \int_{[0,2\pi]}\ln(4\sin^2(\theta/2)) d\theta =  2\pi+8\pi+ \int_{[0,2\pi]}\ln(\sin^2(\theta/2)) d\theta$$

$$= 10\pi+ 2 \int_{[0,2\pi]}\ln(\sin (\theta/2))  d\theta=10\pi+ 4 \int_{[0,\pi]}\ln(\sin \theta)  d\theta=10\pi -4\pi\ln 2$$

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what you did on the first few steps...have you fixed $x$ at the position $(1, 0)$ in order to remove the dependence on it?

Comment: @Riggs thanks for catch, please, see see edits.

Comment: ok cool, I'm also not sure how the 4 is being dropped in the 2nd line?

Comment: @Riggs Sorry, same typo

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure of your first step...you have $|x(1 - e^{i\theta})|$ which is $|x - xe^{i\theta}| = |x - xy|$ which is not the original integrand?

Comment: @Riggs It's not my day, I'm sorry for all the typos here. It should be $y=xe^{i\theta}$

Comment: Its fine, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm...you didn't account for the $i$ when doing the change of variable to $\theta$. I assume you have used the product rule for logs in the first step but we have absolute values here? And if you used the product rule shouldn't we have $2\pi \ln |x|$ and not $2\pi|x|$?

Comment: That should have been 'you didn't account for the $\frac{1}{ixe^{i\theta}}$...